# IE7-8 - Sprite Hack

Tags: css, internet-explorer-8, internet-explorer-7, sprite

I'm using a sprite as an input button.  It works fine in Firefox and > IE8.  However, in IE7&8, the ID value shows over the png graphic.  It looks like this:

(I would embed, but I'm not allowed): [Pre-Hack Sprite](http://img.photobucket.com/albums/v424/pithed2/Pre-Hack.png)

I went through and found a hack for this, minimizing the font size and line height.

```
font-size:0px;      /*IE7-8*/
line-height:0px;    /*IE7-8*/
```

This then created what almost looks like a scratch over the button:

[Post-Hack Sprite](http://img.photobucket.com/albums/v424/pithed2/Post-Hack.png)

Any ideas?  Here's my HTML:

```
<form action='memberSelection' method='post'>
<div id="providersearchopt1">
     ...
<p class="left"><input class="btnsearch" type="submit" id="formSubmit" name="formSubmit" /></p>
```

Here's the CSS:

```
    input[type="submit"].btnsearch {
width:96px;
height:27px;
background-color:transparent;
background-position:0px 0px;
background-image:url(images/btn-search.png);
cursor: pointer;
border: none;
color: transparent;
font-size:0px;      
line-height:0px;        
}
input[type="submit"].btnsearch:hover {
background-position:0px -27px;
background-image:url(images/btn-search.png);
}
```

EDIT - SOLUTION:

Change in CSS:

```
line-height: 100px;        /*IE7-8*/
font-size: 0px:            /*IE7-8*/
```

This will then work in both FF and IE.

Answer (score 1):

You can use type="image", I think hover works on that too with js I forgot really.

or you can make the button using anchor and use JS to submit